# XPath 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select a checkbox on the following public web-page using Selenium XPath from Python and click it to change the checked status.

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fout

For example, the checkbox that I would like to click is located under "***Fluxes/Magnitudes***" and is named "***U***" shown in the picture below.

Upon inspection of this page I built the following XPath to select the checkbox:

```
//*[@type ='checkbox' and @name='U']
```

This returns what I believe to be the correct element, however when I try to run `click()` on the object it fails with the exception `'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

When I look at the functions for this object in a debugger it indeed does not have a click function.

How can this be true for a checkbox?

Is there a different element that has to be selected?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

importe the required Selenium modules at the beginning of automation Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Initialize the WebDriver and navigate to the webpage:

## Initialize the WebDriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fout")
```

Wait for the checkbox element to be visible

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait for the checkbox element to be visible (adjust timeout as needed)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
checkbox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@type='checkbox' and @name='U']")))
```

click the checkbox element

```
checkbox.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was using `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`

Copy paste error from using another line of code

Comment: Hi, Brian. You could improve your question  by including the code you were using since only you could have answered with the information you posted.